# How do you replace parts of the field of a query in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in my database like this:

```
Id   Description ParentId Outline
1    D           null     0001
2    D2          1        00010003
3    D1          1        00010005
4    A           null     0002
5    A3          4        00020003
6    A33         5        000200030004
7    A2          4        00020005
```

Outline it's basically a table with categories and subcategories ordered by outline so it will show as

```
D
  D2
  D1
A
  A3
      A33
  A2
```

when displayed in my application

I wish to order it by the description in each group, so in this case it should look like this

```
A
  A2
  A3
      A33

D
  D1
  D2
```

In my case (since I know it can only have a depth of 3) I LEFT JOIN the table with itself 3 times and build a string for each line with all the descriptions (for example for id 6 the new sorting line looks like this 'A|A3|A33||')

Is there a better way to do this? is there a way to replace for example each 4 digits of the outline with the respective description? in the future the depth may be more than 3 so I don't wish to just keep adding joins, plus it looks sloppy

Thank you

Comment: So you want to order it by Description in each group only? Please add your desired table result.

Comment: I did, it's the third piece of code, basically a tree structure but on each level it is ordered by description

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional sorting:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN ParentId IS NULL THEN Outline
           ELSE SUBSTR(Outline, 1, LENGTH(Outline) - 4)
         END,  
         Description
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY SUBSTR(Outline, 1, LENGTH(Outline) - CASE WHEN ParentId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 4 END), 
         Description
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a945f66afa0c59623d136cda0b444d5b).

Comment: first of all thank you for the answer, unfortunately the way I stated my question was incorrect :( , I printed out an incorrect expected outcome, but you gave me a push in the right direction, I never thought of adding clauses into order by, again thanks for the answer and sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @Cruces then for this sample data a simple `SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY Description`  would do. If not, then you need to clarify.